# Dynamic Bash menu

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm trying to create a dynamic bash menu with some form of error checking that creates Docker Dev Environments.

It creates menu options from the list of folders here: https://github.com/modem7/docker-devenv/tree/master/Environments

This is what I have currently and it mostly works:

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

# Variables
gituser="modem7"
gitrepo="docker-devenv"
gitfolder="Environments"

# Colours
RED="\e[31m"
GREEN="\e[32m"
END="\e[0m"

echo "========================================="
printf "        Checking Dependencies\n"
echo "========================================="
printf "Checking if dependencies are installed...\n"
pkg_list=(docker jq)
tc() { set ${*,,} ; echo ${*^} ; }
for pkg in "${pkg_list[@]}"
do
  titlecase=$(tc $pkg)
  isinstalled=$(dpkg-query -l $pkg > /dev/null 2>&1)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
     then
       printf "~ $titlecase is...${GREEN}installed${END}\n"
     else
       printf "~ $titlecase is...${RED}not installed${END}\n"
       printf "Exiting Script. Install $pkg.\n"
       echo "========================================="
       exit
    fi
done
echo "========================================="

cat << "EOF" 
      ____             _             
     |  _ \  ___   ___| | _____ _ __ 
     | | | |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ | '__|
     | |_| | (_) | (__|   |  __| |   
     |____/ \___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|   
=========================================
EOF

PS3="Choose Option: "
dev_list=($(curl -fks https://api.github.com/repos/$gituser/$gitrepo/contents/$gitfolder | jq '. [] | .name' | tr -d '[]," '))
dev_list_array="${dev_list[*]}"
dev_list_array_pipe="${dev_list_array// /|}"
dev_list+=( "Prune" "Quit" )
echo -e "\nSelect an option:\n"
select dev_name in "${dev_list[@]}"; do
echo -e "\nYou've selected ${GREEN}${dev_name}${END}\n"
lowerdev=$(echo $dev_name | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
    eval "case \"$dev_name\" in
      "$dev_list_array_pipe")
          echo "Creating $dev_name Environment"
          docker buildx build --rm=true --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --load -t $lowerdev:dev https://github.com/$gituser/$gitrepo.git#:$gitfolder/$dev_name \
          && clear \
          && echo "=========================================" \
          && echo "Activating $dev_name Dev Environment..." \
          && echo "Press CTRL + D or type exit to leave the container" \
          && docker run --rm -it --name "$dev_name"Dev"$RANDOM" --hostname "$dev_name"Dev"$RANDOM" "$lowerdev:dev"
          break
          ;;
      "Prune")
          echo "Clearing Docker cache."
          docker system prune -af
          exec bash $0
          ;;
      "Quit")
          echo "Exiting script"
          exit
          ;;
       *)
          echo "invalid option $REPLY"
          ;;
    esac"
done

exit 0
```

The issue I have, is if someone decides to ctrl + C or similar the `docker buildx` part, it can happen that the script doesn't exit neatly.

My bash skills are poor at best (as you can see from the above), but I was thinking that maybe functions would work better in this case as I can add exit codes.

Am I overcomplicating things (even more), or am I on the right track?

Posting here as I think I'm at the end of my current skillset and probably need a second pair of eyes on this.

Cheers!

Comment: Questions need to be narrow and specific to be on-topic here. Not "how can I improve this?", but "how can I fix _very specific problem here_?", with a [mre] built to be the shortest code that lets others see that specific problem (meaning if the problem doesn't relate to, say, printing menus, all the menu-printing parts should be removed).

Comment: For making `ctrl+C` being handled better, consider setting up a `trap` for SIGINT. More advice beyond that would require more details around what constitutes an unclean exit you'd like to avoid, and exactly what behavior you want instead. (Is the problem, say, the terminal being left with color codes that aren't in the state you want? Then maybe a trap that resets it is all you need; but that's just one guess at what "unclean" might mean in the context of this software).